# Can no longer log into graphical desktop

Tags: boot, nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg

I am running standard Ubuntu 18.04, 64-bit (about to upgrade to 20.04). I am hoping for help from a kind person.

Since starting my desktop up this morning, I can no longer boot into or load the graphical/Gnome desktop, or apparently any sort of graphical X server UI...

This is weird because it literally worked fine yesterday, and my Windows 10 partition boots up and works 100%. (I require Windows for my job for the time being.)

When I boot into Ubuntu, I get the text-based login screen, but if I run the command `startx`, the screen blanks for a second, and then it drops me back into the standard text-based shell.

Here is a video of it happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOPHHA-3kbg

And here is a screenshot of what happens after I attempt to run `startx`: https://imgur.com/a/cHTFWsU

As you can see, I can detect no sort of error message. I am truly at a loss for words.

At the same time, I am not connected to my WiFi in this text shell, and since I'm no programmer (I use Ubuntu because I love it, not because I know anything about computers), I have no way to fix this or connect to the web.

I could really do with some help from a kind person.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you start an older kernel?

Comment: I can try, think of me like a granny who doesn't understand computers (even though I'm an average guy). Ive never done it before. What do I do?

Comment: please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus

Comment: Ok, I will try that and get back to you in 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Ok, not change that I can see. I tried the older kernel, and it seems no change.
Here is a screenshot after trying ```startx``` https://imgur.com/a/wb0ypuD
And here is a video of the process: https://youtu.be/YcJ68bsEnl4 (Might need 2 minutes to process)

Comment: My last idea ist to add kernel boot option `module_blacklist=nvidia`  this prevents  nvidia from loading for the current start. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: @nobody I added the parameter, same result, though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i know that this isn't really an "Answer" and should be written as a comment, but i don't have enough reputation for comments and would like to help to narrow down the reason for this behavior.

You could check the current [target](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Targets) of systemd:

- Run `systemctl get-default`
- If the output is **not** `graphical.target` change it to graphical:

  - `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

You could try to manually start the display manager:

- Run `sudo systemctl start gdm`

You could check the Xserver log files for any error messages:

- `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | less`
- `cat /var/log/Xorg.1.log | less`
- etc.

It would also be helpful to know if you have made any changes to the system the last time Ubuntu booted successfully.

---

Lastly, i would rather suggest you to backup all the files you want to keep and then do a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 since you're going to upgrade to it anyway. Also, you may want to use something like [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) in the future, which allows you to roll your machine back to a known working configuration when something like this happens.

Comment: Thanks I will try this all, but it's really late in my time zone, so I'll have to try it tomorrow. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: I tried to comment but it was too much, so see my comment as an "answer"

Comment: I replied to your suggestions as an "answer" because it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I just reinstalled the Ubuntu desktop with `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and it seems to work now. So, still no idea what caused the problem, but I guess it works now?